# Rails 3: sending local variable in the controller to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

new to rails and really new to jquery. I've set up some AJAX page rendering by adding `respond_to :html, :js` to my controller and `respond_to @Posts` in posts#index method. It render's my views/posts/_posts.html.erb partial using AJAX, however, I needed the html response to direct to the same place so I tried adding a `respond_to do |format|` block.

posts#index

```
@posts = ...

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render 'posts/_posts' }
  format.js   { respond_with @posts }
```

This works and sends my my `:html` response to the correct view, but I have a problem with variables. My posts#index uses an @posts variable, but my `views/posts/index.js.erb` files does this:

```
$('#stream').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "posts", :posts => @posts) %>');
```

So my `views/posts/_posts.html.erb` looks for `posts` instead of `@posts`

```
<% posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'shared/feed_item', :feed_item => post %>
<% end %>
```

I tried sending the local variable from the controller like below but this didn't work:

posts#index

```
@posts = ...

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render 'posts/_posts', :posts => @posts }
  format.js   { respond_with @posts }
```

Any ideas how to send get this working? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got something similar to work like this:

`format.html { render "posts/_posts", :locals => { :posts => @posts } }`